# url problems for my website

Tags: .net, asp.net, url

I have a page where I present a specific product (book, cd etc) which is like this:

> http://gramma.ro/Site/DetaliiProdus.aspx?c=m1&p=1493&s1=40&s2=71

I do not understand why, *sometimes*, some bots try to access these details pages with urls like:

`http://gramma.ro/Site/DetaliiProdus.aspx?c=m1&amp;p=1493&amp;s1=40&amp;s2=71`

And of course, this url no longer can be interpreted in ASP.NET like a usual url so I cannot extract the parameters like usual (`Request.QueryString`)...

1. Do you have any idea how this bot has scanned the site in this way? Because nowhere on my site I have urls with `&` replaced by `&amp;`
2. Do you see a work-around? I cannot replace `&amp;` with `&` on the fly for the initial request...

**Ps**: Oh yes, I know that if I do url rewriting I no longer have such a problem but I cannot change at this moment all the site just because of this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Can you see in the IIS logs what kind of bot that is? Might be an unimportant one, so you could simply ignore it.
2. As a relatively simple workaround, you can do a URL Rewrite like this (depending on your QueryString combinations this can be adjusted): check for

   ```
   (.*)&amp;(.*)&amp;(.*)&amp;(.*)
   ```

and redirect to (something like - this hasn't been tested)

> {R:1}&{R:2}&{R:3}&{R:4}

If there are different numbers of QueryString parameters, you could write different rules, starting with the highest amount (or find a better rule). This can really be done without changing the whole site.

But first I'd search for other reasons why this happens.

A third way (maybe the nicest) would be to use "SEO-friendly URLs" anyway instead of visible QueryStrings. It may help with your rankings, too. Check http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx (or many other sites) for more information.

Comment: I've been able to find out the ip of the bot and doing whois it appears: `Title: WordPress.com`. So seems that wordpress bot has some problems..?

Comment: So it seems. However, you can still apply the Rewrite Rule to your IIS (or your web.config).